# How does the for loop work in the code give?

Tags: c++, loops

```
 int n = 123456; vector<int> v;
 for(; n; n/=10)
   v.push_back( n%10 );
```

The loop does not seem to have a control variable. If it has one kindly explain how it works. Thank you:)

Comment: The Control variable is `n` itself. `n` evaluates to `true` if `n != 0`

Comment: Your C++ book should have a full and complete explanation of how the `for` loop works. If there's something in your book's explanation that you don't fully understand, you can ask about it, and quote the specific parts that you don't understand. But stackoverflow.com is not a replacement for a C++ book.

Comment: *The loop does not seem to have a control variable*, really?

Comment: _"The loop does not seem to have a control variable"_ .  Please elaborate on what you are thinking.  Where do you expect to see the "control variable"?  I see it in your code, but I don't understand why you don't see it.

Answer (score 2):

This is propably a duplicate of some other, already accepted answer. Nevertheless, here's the answer.

[for-loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) work as the following

```
for(init; condition; stuff)
```

each of these is optional. In your case, init was left out, `n` is the condition, which means as long as `n` is true (which is, as long as `n` is not zero), and stuff (the thing that happens at the end of every loop cycle) divides your n by 10.

One last thing, please use a C++-reference or a search engine the next time. A similar question has been asked a thousand times before :)